# Animated Splash in Flex Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flash-builder, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I'm developing a mobile application to BlackBerry 10 in Flash Builder 4.6. I want to make an animated splash. In android its really easy to do this with anim resources and just some images. Does anybody knows if there are something similar to do in Flex? Or some way to do an animated Splash? Thanks to any advice.